# Change button HREF depending on the address bar URL

Tags: javascript

I have a website that users with an affiliate URL often visit, for example:

```
https://demowebsite.com/?ref=550
```

There is a link that initially has an URL:

```
https://demowebsite.com/register

<a href="https://demowebsite.com/register" id="reg" class="btn btn-info">Register</a>
```

How can I make that if there is a part with a ref ID in the address bar like `https://demowebsite.com/?ref=550`, then the href is transformed into the following by click:

```
https://subdomain.demowebsite.com/ref/
```

and add the ref ID at the end as an append:

```
https://subdomain.demowebsite.com/ref/550
```

And if there is no affiliate part in the address bar, then the link would remain the same.

```
<a href="https://demowebsite.com/register" id="reg" class="btn btn-info">Register</a>
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: so.. just to make sure.. if I go to `https://demowebsite.com/?ref=550` the button linking to `https://demowebsite.com/register` would be there?

Comment: What have you tried so far, what did you try to research? This site is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `location` object given in tabs

```
<script>
var href=location.href
if(href.includes('ref')){
  document.getElementById('reg')
  .href="https://demowebsite.com/ref/"  +  href.split('=')[1]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the URL api

```js
const affRef = (loc) => {
  const url = new URL(loc || location.href); // we can pass a url to test
  const ref = url.searchParams.get("ref");
  if (ref) {
    url.pathname += ref;
    url.searchParams.delete("ref")
    url.hostname = "subdomain."+url.hostname;
  }
  return url.href
};

document.getElementById("reg1").href = affRef("https://demowebsite.com/register"); // nothing should happen
document.getElementById("reg2").href = affRef("https://demowebsite.com/?ref=550"); // changed
```

```html
1. <a href="https://demowebsite.com/register" id="reg1" class="btn btn-info">Register</a><br/>

2. <a href="https://demowebsite.com/register" id="reg2" class="btn btn-info">Register</a>
```

On your site you would not need the LOC or pass the URL

```js
const affRef = () => {
  const url = new URL(location.href);
  const ref = url.searchParams.get("ref");
  if (ref) {
    url.pathname += ref;
    url.searchParams.delete("ref")
    url.hostname = "subdomain."+url.hostname;
  }
  return url.href
};

document.getElementById("reg1").href = affRef();
```

```html
1. <a href="https://demowebsite.com/register" id="reg1" class="btn btn-info">Register</a><br/>

2. <a href="https://demowebsite.com/register" id="reg2" class="btn btn-info">Register</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change it from the place where the users are being sent. I'm not very sure, but the code would look something like this:

```js
var searchBar; //Assign the Search bar it's value through ID or however you can

if (searchBar=="www.demowebsite.com/register") {
document.getElementById("a").href = ""; //Your desired link
}
else {
document.getElementById("a").href = ""; //Your desired link
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.demowebsite.com" id="a"> Register </a>
```